# CiviEvent location geocoding broken

Tags: civievent, geocoding

We are on CiviCRM 4.7.11 - when adding events we have noticed that the geocoding is no longer working.  We use Google, are entering a valid UK address, and the API keys are valid and not exhausted.

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in CRM_Core_Page_AJAX_Location::getLocBlock() (line 262 of /home/ace/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page/AJAX/Location.php)

Is anyone else seeing this behaviour please?

Thank you!

Comment: We're going to need the following information:

1. Do you have a test site that you can replicate the behaviour on? If so, please enable backtrace. And re-run
2. Regardless, please look in the civicrm logs.
3. What is your geocoding provider? Which extension did you install to get this?

Thanks!

Comment: There is nothing in the log - interestingly we have now realised that this error only occurs on one address, The British Library at 96 Euston Road, so we have entered their lat/long manually. Thank you for the offer of help though!

Comment: Glad you resolved it! You should report the error to the Geocoding module maker though.